# How can I install fpoirotte/cryptal with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I can't install https://packagist.org/packages/fpoirotte/cryptal. Per packagist.org I should be able to do `composer require fpoirotte/cryptal` via the CLI but whenever I try to do so I get the following error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package fpoirotte/cryptal.

  Did you mean one of these?
      fpoirotte/cryptal
      fpoirotte/cryptal-hash
      fpoirotte/cryptal-sodium
      fpoirotte/cryptal-mcrypt
      fpoirotte/cryptal-openssl


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I'm able to install other composer packages without issue. It's just this one that's having issues..

Comment: hmm did you tried by typing it not copy pasting it? i have encounter some  weird issue like this specially on windows git bash

Comment: @MarkB - Yah - I tried typing it out and copy / pasting it. Neither worked. I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that the package has the type "composer-plugin" idk. But even if that were the case I'd expect packagist to give me the correct command instead of one that doesn't even work...

Comment: @yivi - I'll be trying it out this evening. I'm at my 9-5pm job atm and the question was unrelated to my job. It was related to a side project I'm working on in my free time and I'm not gonna dabble in that while at work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default minimum stability for composer is "stable".

From the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability):

> "minimum-stability" (root-only): This defines the default behavior for filtering packages by stability. This defaults to stable, so if you rely on a dev package, you should specify it in your file to avoid surprises.

And on the other hand, the package you are trying to install only has a "master" branch and no version tags, so it is considered a "dev" dependency.

You have to options to install this package:

#### Edit your composer.json to include:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Although this changes your minimum stability requirements for the whole project, so it may not be ideal.

#### Require a specific version

If you do `composer require fpoirotte/cryptal:master-dev` you'll be able to install this package keeping your minimum-stability settings to `stable`.

---

I do not know what version of composer you are running, but it may be worth to update it. The error I get with my version is much more explicit:

> **[InvalidArgumentException]**
>
> Could not find a version of package fpoirotte/cryptal matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.